# Prometheus always picks the first value only

Tags: prometheus

Let's say prometheus pulls data from my server every 10 sec and I want to have graph of the loading time of the index page, during that 10 sec period the index page was loaded 3 times. I tried all the combinations and can't get it to work, it always just picks the first value.

```
index_loading_time 100
index_loading_time 110
index_loading_time 105
```

I tried sending it as a summary and Histogram and it just picked the first value, I expected it to pick all the values, or at least insert the avg of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Summary or Histogram from the client libraries. That'd produce something like:

```
index_loading_time_seconds_count 3
index_loading_time_seconds_sum 315
```

from which you can calculate an average using `irate(index_loading_time_seconds_sum[1m]) / irate(index_loading_time_seconds_count[1m])`

Comment: so I should sum it up by myself thanks not clear from the docs

Comment: You should have to do any summing by yourself, leave that to the client library.